# Xamlparse Exception occured

Tags: xamlparseexception

I am getting this error again and again in silver light code .It says, The invocation of the constructor on type "LookupControl.SilverCrmLookup" that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. Though there is no error in code .

Answer (score 0):

Check your XAML there must be something wrong in there ..